# Jquery AJAX - iRail API liveboard error

Tags: jquery, ajax

So I am trying to use the iRail API (api.irail.be) I want to implent this in Ionic in a later stage but for now I want to try using it in JQuery using Ajax.

i want to try this but it doesn't work the same way
This is the second thing I want to try and I want to try to get the station

```
   $.ajax({ 
method: "GET",
url: "https://api.irail.be/liveboard/?id=BE.NMBS.008892007&format=json", 
})
 .done(function(res) { 
console.log(res.liveboard['1'].station); 
 });
```

This is the code I'm using but I get an error that the 1 cant  is not defined and can't be read
I hope someone can help me and explain how I can use this API the right way

Best regards 
Ditger

Comment: You need to use `res.station` instead of `res.liveboard['1'].station`

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! that worked, I have been trying things on my own and I came up with this             console.log(res.departures["departure"],["platform"]);
I wanted to try to display the platform since that is within the departure array but I am not sure how I can look in that array, so I hope you can help me and I'm sorry im new to using API's

Comment: You can install [extension from Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jsonview/chklaanhfefbnpoihckbnefhakgolnmc/related?hl=vi) and open your browser with https://api.irail.be/liveboard/?id=BE.NMBS.008892007&format=json

Comment: I figured it out! thanks